# Bucket policy denying S3:DeleteBucket and S3:DeleteObject still deletes objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've applied the following bucket policy to a `my-bucket.myapp.com` S3 bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PreventAccidentalDeletePolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PreventAccidentalDelete",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject”
            ],
            "Resource": [
                “arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket.myapp.com”,
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket.myapp.com/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then in the console, when I attempt to delete the bucket (right-click, Delete) I get the error I'm expecting: `Access Denied`.

BUT, and here's the rub, the problem is that it still deletes all the objects that are *in* the bucket

Why does this happen?

And it even happens with a versioned bucket. It just wipes all the versions and the objects are GONE.

Comment: I tried this, I am facing same issue. Maybe you can report this to AWS

Comment: I tried. Their forums are pretty useless. Maybe I'll send through a support request if I can.

Comment: Yes support request with call or chat usually solves the issue for me

Comment: Yes, very interesting! The "Delete Bucket" command is not an API call, it actually triggers code in the Management Console to delete objects and then delete the bucket (like a Wizard). For some reason, it has the ability to delete objects even when the user can't delete it directly in the console.

Comment: are you deleting the bucket using root account? this might be a problem. But still as S3 policy is a resource based policy you can even deny root as you have mentioned "*" in principal.

Comment: Yes, this is using the root account in the console. That's the scenario I'm attempting to mitigate: accidental deletion when root in the console. Not likely, but I've got a need for very high durability. I'm also backing up to a separate account in a separate region, but that's another story ... The bottom line is that the bucket policy I've applied is *not* behaving as expected.

Comment: The AWS recommendation, from what I can garner in their docs, is to use a versioned bucket. But this wipes out all versions too, so I really don't see the point of that.

Comment: I ended up sending a "Account" support request through the console since that's all it allows me to do. They got back to me saying that because I referenced a third-party forum (Stackoverflow), they don't support it. So I guess AWS just doesn't give a shit about whether you zork and entire bucket because of their bug or not.

Answer (score 2):

Recommended best practice is to not use the root account aside from creating your initial IAM user so you can add restrictions to prevent such an incident. In the event someone has a use-case that needs this behavior programmatically they don't want to put limits in the system as "safe guards". It's up to the user to follow best practice and implement the necessary safeguards as applicable to their situation

The exact process for how amazon authorizes actions on s3 objects: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-s3-evaluates-access-control.html

Section 2|A on this document describes behavior applied to root account in user context: " If the request is made using root credentials of an AWS account, Amazon S3 skips this step."