# Deleting S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have power user access and wanted to delete a bucket, but am getting access denied to policy file update. As far as i know only one role id is added am not sure that the role id belongs to.

I tried many CLI commands to delete it.

`s3 rb s3://bucket-name`

Error:

> ```
> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteBucket
> operation: Access Denied
> ```

Is there any way to delete forcefully?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40122826/bucket-policy-denying-s3deletebucket-and-s3deleteobject-still-deletes-objects

Comment: If you can't update the policy file then your user does not have proper permissions.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski i can't access policy file, and shows me access denied.

Comment: Your IAM identity needs to have permissions to both s3:GetBucketPolicy and s3:PutBucketPolicy Can you set them?

Comment: Okey Lukasz, thank you!

Comment: I am glad it worked (I presume). Can you accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IAM identity needs to have permissions to both s3:GetBucketPolicy and s3:PutBucketPolicy

Once set, policy file can be edited and bucket deleted.